# How can I get the serial number of the Mac, using shell or AppleScript

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

[image]

How can I  get the serial number of the Mac, using shell or  AppleScript

Comment: Please add the screenshot as an image, not as a link. Moreover, what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 2):

In shell you can use either `ioreg`:

```
ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber
```

or `system_profiler`:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Serial
```